# Using Javascript to Add/Remove Users in Rails Admin Interface

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a Ruby on Rails application, I want to be able to place a User's username in a input text box, press an 'Add' button, and have them appear underneath with their details. Then, I can simply remove them from the list if I want using another button.

How does one connect Javascript and Rails database to complete such a task specifically with those buttons? While Javascript isn't a strength of mine, I'm more puzzled by how to extract and modify the Rails database using Javascript. For reference, I'm also using MongoDB.

What would be the best way to approach this?

[image: Popular::User UI Add/Remove]

Here is the jQuery and AJAX code that I'm using to 'POST' to the server endpoint 'admin/popular/users.json', but I'm not sure how to get Rails to create a new user in the database using my Popular::User model.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-to-popular-users-button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var addToPopularUsersBtn = $(this);
        var userToBeAdded = $('input[name=popular_user]').val();
        var data = { 'popular_user': {'username': userToBeAdded, 'category': 'popular'} };
        var url = "/admin/popular/users.json";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(e) {
                alert('Great success!');
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Here's my Popular::User model:

```
class Popular::User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  POPULAR = 'popular'

  field :category, default: POPULAR
  index :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id

  def self.popular
      user_ids = self.where( :category => POPULAR ).map(&:id)

      User.where(:_id.in => user_ids)
  end
```

Comment: I have the UI set up which is a table and standard button layout. I'll edit with an image. I also have the database querying for the right users with a particular 'category' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure this out with a bit of testing. But, basically, you can either do this with AJAX/jQuery or with Rails inherent RESTful architecture, i.e., HTTP verbs like calling :delete, and associating it with a particular UI button.

One important idea that you should recognize with AJAX is that whatever data you send to the right server endpoint with a 'POST' or 'DELETE' verb or what have you, it will get picked up by the appropriate controller action. In other words, if I'm sending data via 'POST' to the '/popular/users.json' endpoint to create something, the `def create` method will be able to manipulate data afterwards. Then, you can assign the data to an ivar in the controller action to be interpreted and manipulated in the UI view corresponding to the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with rails framework, but you can do it using ajax. You can send an ajax post request to controller method which will creae a user, create a table row(or recreate the table), and returnd html place in table.

A simple example is:

```
$.ajax({
 type:'post',
 data:{} //user data,
 dataType: 'json', //or any other
 url: 'page_or_method',  //page or method that will return html
 success: function (data) {
     $('div#userTable').html(data); //in case data contains the table
 }
});
```

Read about $.ajax method (jQuery), or you can use XMLHttpRequest if you don't whant to use jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that I would need jQuery and AJAX to accomplish this. It's actually not for creating NEW users, but adding in ones that already exist and updating an attribute. I'll try and read up more on it.

Comment: Ok, I set the AJAX code up with some jQuery. I'll update the original post with the code. My issue now is that I'm not sure how to create the Popular::User because it's not working and not showing up in my db when I check the rails console.